# Facebook app posting to page successfully, but posts are not visible to non-developers. Do I really have to review for an app with 1 user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have setup a facebook app to post images / videos to one particular fan page. It requests 'publish_actions' and 'manage_pages permissions. It is in developer mode and I have no intention to expand the functionality beyond posting to this single facebook page.

The code works correctly, it posts to the correct page and everything looks good whilst logged into the developer account / page admin (same account). ***But other facebook users cannot see the posts that have been made via the app***. I was under the impression that apps didn't need to go through the review process for internal apps such as these?

Heres a quick stripped down version of the code for posting to the page:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($settings['app_id'], $settings['secret']);
//This is user access_token not the pages.
$session = new FacebookSession( $settings['access_token'] );

$pageTokenResponse = (new FacebookRequest(
             $session
                , 'GET', '/' . $settings['page_id'] 
                , array( 'fields' => 'access_token' )
          ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphPage::className());

//Retrieved Page Token
$pageToken = $pageTokenResponse->getProperty("access_token");

uploadUrlToFacebook($imgurl, $item->get_title(), $session, $pageToken, $settings['page_id']);

function uploadUrlToFacebook($url, $title, $session, $pageToken, $pageId){
    $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'POST',
      "/$pageId/photos",
      array (
          'access_token' => $pageToken
         ,'url' => $url
        ,'message' => $title
      )
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
}
```

I'm sure there is a stupid error either somewhere in the code or my apps setup but why can *I* see the posts but nobody else can ?

Comment: If you look at your app's settings on Facebook, there's one that controls this. I believe it's called Sandbox Mode. While it's enabled only the developers can interact with the app, so that they can test it out before it "goes live".

Comment: It looks like the sandbox mode has now been replaced with a live / not live toggle but apps using publish_actions like this one have to go through a review process. Which I want to avoid really as it will never be opened up to other users anyway.

Comment: You don't need to be approved to take the app live. Just click the button

Comment: Setting your app live has nothing to do with review. You _must_ set your app live if you want content published via it to be visible to the general public.

Comment: Yup this was it. I had already selected some items for review before I properly understood the process so I ended up in a state of not being able to make it live as I had pending review items. I deleted the permissions from the review queue, made live and all is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had already selected some items for review before I properly understood the process so I ended up in a state of not being able to make the app live as I had pending review items. I deleted the permissions from the review queue, made the app live and all is good.

Answer (score -1):

I think while authenticating Fb App you given "only me" visibility for Publish Actions.

go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Select your App .
Then Check this . "App visibility and post audience"